# Calculate multiple circle fragment rotations

Tags: javascript, css, math, svg

So I have 4 SVG circles, which I'm using `stroke-dash` to mask. And the general idea is that they're supposed to make up one full circle based on their percentage.

I've gotten the length of each segment, and when I rotate them manually I see that it all adds up. But I can't figure out how to calculate the rotation of each segment. Under is a jsbin link to show how far I've gotten:

http://jsbin.com/lutodomujo/1/

Also, if there is better way to solve this, I'd be happy to hear it. The only thing that has to work is the hover effect as shown in the example.

By the way, the following line is a purely wild guess (as you may have noticed):

```
var rotate = (Math.sin((c-prevRotate)/100) * Math.PI)*100; // ?
```

And it is, as far as I know, the only one I need help to figure out.

```js
var prevRotate = 0;
$('circle').each(function (i) {
  var r = $(this).attr('r');
  var val = $(this).data('perc');
  var c = Math.PI * (r * 2);

  var pct = ((100 - val) / 100) * c;
  var rotate = (Math.sin((c-prevRotate)/100) * Math.PI)*100;

  $(this).css({
    strokeDasharray: c,
    strokeDashoffset: pct,
    transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)'
  });
  prevRotate += pct;
});
```

```css
svg { width: 300px; }
circle {
  stroke-width: 3;
  transform-origin: center;
}
circle:hover {stroke-width: 5}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164 164">
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#A5D2C6" cx="82" cy="82" r="80" data-perc="40"/>
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#000000" cx="82" cy="82" r="80" data-perc="30"/>
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#EBE6B7" cx="82" cy="82" r="80" data-perc="20"/>
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#F1AAA6" cx="82" cy="82" r="80" data-perc="10"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: If my answer is correct, can you accept it please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some change and it s work :

```
var prevRotate = 0;
$('circle').each(function (i) {
  var r = $(this).attr('r');
  var val = $(this).data('perc');
  var c = Math.PI * (r * 2);

  var pct = ((100 - val) / 100) * c;
  var rotate = prevRotate;

  $(this).css({
    strokeDasharray: c,
    strokeDashoffset: pct,
    transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)'
  });
  prevRotate += (360*val/100); 
});
```